# Handle JavaScript map framework - fix bounds or deny to swipe the map out of the view

Tags: javascript, html, dictionary, leaflet

I just work on a JavaScript based map (leaflet is the framework).
The problem is I do not have much experience with maps in HTML and JavaScript.
I want to achieve that the map does not disapper after swiping to the left or right border (or even bot/top). Is there a solution to fix the bounds to the view?

I set it up like this:

```
var bounds = [[0,0], [750,499]];
var image = L.imageOverlay('map.png', bounds).addTo(map);
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Would be nice if someone has a suggestion to this problem.

Greetings

Tobias

**UPDATE:**
I found an acceptable solution:

```
var bounds = [[0,0], [750,499]];

var map = L.map('map', {
        crs: L.CRS.Simple,
        minZoom: -1,
        maxBounds: bounds,
});
```

As u can see in the init process of the map i allocate maxBound. With this solution there are not fixed bounds as i asked for, but the map always swipes to it initial point back!